# quoting individual characters(words) in a string on java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

learner here, so bear with me if this question seems absurd. Say I am trying to quote characters in a string and not the string itself, how do I go about doing that?
what I mean is;

given: `var str = "i wondered what a scattered brained computer does to remain sane"`

and I want :

`var output to read = ""i" "wonder" "what" "a" "scattered" "brained" "computer" "does" "to" "remain" "sane""`

what do you think is the best action to take?

Comment: [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: I've removed your [tag:java] question tag. Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, that questions tags and question titles are the most important parts of your question, and that if either are off, you won't get the correct experts to see your question.

Comment: Are you asking how to add quotes programmatically or hard code them in the string?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer would be the following:

```
var output = str.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reach your desired solution with `String#replace`, which will wrap each single word in quotation marks `"`.

```js
const str = 'I wondered what a scattered brained computer does to remain sane';

let res = str.replace(/\w+/g, '"$&"');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of useful built in methods in JavaScript for this:

1. [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) - performed on a string, it "splits" it into an array at each instance of the substring provided. i.e. `'abc'.split('b'); // ['a','c']`
2. [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - performed on an array, it "joins" each element together with the given string. i.e. `['a','c'].join('d'); // 'adc'`

So how would you utilize these? Easy!

```js
var str = "i wondered what a scattered brained computer does to remain sane";
var output = str.split(" ").join('" "'); // Note: javascript strings can be delimited with both `'` and `"`, which comes in handy!
console.log('"' + output + '"'); // Finally, add the missing `"` on the first and last word and print
```

So what happens if there's multiple spaces? What if the input is like `var str = "Hello  world!"` (note there are 2 spaces between `"hello"` and `"world"`).

There's a more advanced way to select portions of a string in programming called [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), they can be confusing and tricky, but they can be powerful when used correctly. This will allow us to split the string on any number of spaces between words, so you won't get things like `""` showing up in the output.

```js
var str = "Hello  world!";
var output = str.trim().split(/\s+/g).join('" "'); // Here we use the .trim() method to remove any spaces at the beginning or the end of the string, we split on as many spaces in a row as we can, then join
console.log('regex: "' + output + '"');

// what would the old method look like?
var str = "Hello  world!";
console.log('no regex: "' + str.split(' ').join('" "') + '"');
```